# How to use a PowerShell script in a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that executes fine manually, but when I want to execute the script with a scheduled task, it doesn't work.

I want to open an application (Qlikview) if `toto.xml` file exist.

Someone can help me please?

In Shedule Configuration:

- Execute if user not connected: Checked
- Run with highest privileges: Checked
- Program/script: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- Arguments: `-File "C:\Users\Xda\Script\Vscript.ps1"`

Script:

```
if ( Test-Path C:\Users\Xda\Script\toto.xml ) 
{
    & "C:\Program Files\QlikView\Qv.exe" "D:\Qlikview\Stats.qvw"
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your approach. Check eventlog and task history and add logging to your script to get an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: `Run whether user is logged on or not` - If this radio button is selected, tasks will not run interactively.  To make a task run interactively, select the `Run only when user is logged on` radio button.

Comment: Try to set it up your ST based on this [article](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/004_SharePointActions/012_SchedulingPowerShell.htm).

Comment: What OS version you are at? I remember I had some issues while running scripts via scheduler at Windows Server 2003. If so you may try run it like this: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -command "& {C:\Users\Xda\Script\Vscript.ps1}"

Comment: Thanks you all for your Help.

@beatcracker your solution work fine for me :)